# Inserting fetched data from mysql into div using ajax call on each click

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax, fetch

So, I imagine this is pretty simple but I can't really wrap my head around it, I am pretty new to AJAX so bear with me, I have created simple REST API for my little project with native php which gets characters info from MySQL database and I want to insert that data for each character on each click of a link,idea is this
[simple page with links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhklI.png) and the right side of the page is the div which I created to insert that data in,

This is my code for ajax currently which doesn't work

```
var title = document.getElementById('charactertitle');
var desc = document.getElementById('characterdesc');
var buttonClick = document.getElementsByClassName('content-button');

buttonClick.addEventListener('click', loadCharacterInfo);

function loadCharacterInfo(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.open('GET','/api/characters/read.php',true);

 xhr.onload = function(){
   var characters = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

  output = '';

  for(var i in characters){
    output += characters[i].title;
  }

  title.innerHTML = output;
}
 }

  xhr.send();
```

and this is the code for the right side of the page with simple div with 2 p tags

```
    <div class="flex-shrink-1">
            <div class="card bg-dark text-white">
                    <img class="card-img" src="img/charactersbg.jpg" alt="no image">
                    <div class="card-img-overlay">
                      <p class="card-title display-4" id="charactertitle"></p>
                      <p class="card-text" id="characterdesc"></p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
```

This is the read function which basically gets data from Database end encodes it to JSON `

```
include '../../config/Database.php';
include '../../models/Characters.php';

// Instantiate DB & Connect
$database = new Database();
$db = $database->connect();

// Instantiate blog post object
$chars = new Characters($db);

//Blog Post Query
$result = $chars->read();

// Check if any characters
$num = $result->rowCount();

// Check if any characters
if ($num > 0) {
   // Post array
   $chars_arr = [];
   $chars_arr['data'] = array();

   while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
       extract($row);

       $chars_item = [
           'id' => $id,
           'title' => $title,
           'description' => html_entity_decode($description)
       ];

       // Push to data
       array_push($chars_arr['data'], $chars_item);
   }

   // Turn to JSON & output
   echo json_encode($chars_arr);
} else {
    // No posts
   echo json_encode(
        ['message' => 'No posts found']
    );
}
```

I tested the read function on Postman so it works, I also was wondering if I needed to create read_single type of function which only gets one character info, but I still can't really display it on div so figuring out that is main worry

Anyway thanks in advance for answers, I would love some help :)
`

Answer (score 0):

console.log() is handy for debugging AJAX methods.

In browsers like Chrome and Firefox you can open the console with Ctrl-shift-i

```
xhr.onload = function() {
  var characters = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
  console.log(characters);
```

Then you can read the console to see if the `characters` variable looks the way you expect it to and if you are parsing it correctly.

Now, from a quick read it looks like the PHP side is creating a multi-dimensional array (turned into a JSON object), while the client-side `loadCharacterInfo` function is expecting a one-dimensional array.

It appears that if all goes well in the PHP script, the only property of the Javascript object `characters` is `data`, which contains the characters array. If no characters are found it looks like the only property is `message`, which contains the error message.

i.e. On the PHP side, the top level of `$chars_array` only has one item, `data`. There is no `title` etc. in the top level. It is the second level, `$chars_array['data']`, that holds the array of characters, each with properties like `title`, etc.

```
var resp = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
if (resp.data) {
  // resp.data should correspond to the PHP $chars_array['data']
  var characters = res.data;
  for (var i in characters) {      
    // display as you wish
  }
} else if (resp.message) {
  // e.g. This could be the 'No posts found' message.
  var msg = resp.message; // display as you wish
}
```

Comment: sorry for late answer, i tried this but problem is it displays same when i click any link, i can't figure out how to distribute each data for each click